# Applicative [] の <*> の実装はどのようにして読む（解釈する）のでしょうか？

Tags: haskell

[箱で考えるFunctor、ApplicativeそしてMonad - Qiita](https://qiita.com/suin/items/0255f0637921dcdfe83b) に載っているサンプルのコード（下記引用）の挙動がすこし不思議だなと思ったので、実際の処理は、実装を読めばわかるだろうと考えました。

> ```
> > [(*2), (+3)] <*> [1, 2, 3]
> [2, 4, 6, 4, 5, 6]
> ```

そこで

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#%3C%2A%3E を見てみると

> ```
> (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
> (<*>) = liftA2 id
> ```

となっており、じゃあ次は `leftA2` を見ないといけないんだなと考えみにいってみると、

> ```
> liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
> liftA2 f x = (<*>) (fmap f x)
> ```

となって、また `<*>` が出てきてしまいました。

再帰ぽいような動きなんでしょうか？　これ以上どう読んだらいいのかわからなくなってしまいました。

`(<*>) (fmap f x)` はどのように解釈すればいいんでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

読んでおられたところは，前後の文脈を含めるとここです

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    {-# MINIMAL pure, ((<*>) | liftA2) #-}
    -- | Lift a value.
    pure :: a -> f a
    -- | Sequential application.
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    (<*>) = liftA2 id
    -- | Lift a binary function to actions.
    liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
    liftA2 f x = (<*>) (fmap f x)
```

つまり，ここは（インスタンスに関係なく） `Applicative` の定義を作っているところ（「`Applicative` っていうのはこういうもの」）で，`(<*>) = liftA2 id` などはそのデフォルト実装を与えるものです．おっしゃるとおり `<*>`と `liftA2` の定義は循環しています．これは無意味なことではなくて，あとから何かの型（たとえばリスト）を Applicative にするときに，どちらかだけ定義すれば良いようになっています（たとえば， `<*>` の定義だけ具体的に書き下せば，`liftA2` の定義は `<*> (fmap f x)` で決まる）．

具体的な定義は，同じページのもう少し下，こういうところにあります

```
instance Applicative [] where
    {-# INLINE pure #-}
    pure x    = [x]
    {-# INLINE (<*>) #-}
    fs <*> xs = [f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]
    {-# INLINE liftA2 #-}
    liftA2 f xs ys = [f x y | x <- xs, y <- ys]
    {-# INLINE (*>) #-}
    xs *> ys  = [y | _ <- xs, y <- ys]
```

[リスト内包表記](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension) が使われていて一瞬面食らうかもしれませんが，少なくとも定義の循環はないのが見て取れると思います．